# PowerShell cmdlets Get-AdfsProperties doesn't contain EnableIdpInitiatedSignonpage property

Tags: powershell, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs, idp

I'm creating ADFS configuration relying party for SAML ASPNET, but when I type `Get-AdfsProperties` cmdlets into PowerShell for enabling `EnableIdpInitiatedSignonpage True`, the output doesn't contain `EnableIdpInitiatedSignonpage` property.

Why `EnableIdpInitiatedSignonpage` property is missing ?

[image: See Image]

when executing the query `Set-AdfsProperties –EnableIdpInitiatedSignonPage $True`,
showing error message

[image: Error Message Image]

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a legacy version of Windows and legacy ADFS, this property is not there. For if you view the MS provided documentation for WS216 and higher...

[AD FS Troubleshooting - Idp-Initiated Sign-On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/troubleshooting/ad-fs-tshoot-initiatedsignon)

The property is there.

[image]

> [Get-AdfsProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/get-adfsproperties?view=win10-ps)

... in some cases, not all properties are shown by default. You have to use cmdlets like...

```
cmdletname | Select-Object '*'
```

or

```
cmdletname  | Get-Member
```

or

```
cmdletname | Get-Member -Force
```

... to see them all.

If you just to this...

```
Get-AdfsProperties | Select-Object EnableIdpInitiatedSignonpage
```

... you should get a display of that setting and Setting the property is similar

```
Set-AdfsProperties –EnableIdpInitiatedSignonPage $True
```

Update

As per your comment ...

> ...I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter ...
>
> ... how can I achieve Enable IdpInitiatedSignon Page...

***On legacy Windows/ADFS (circa prior to WS2016) it is on by default.*** There is no need to manually/way to enable it. Just go to the IDP page.

```
https://adfs.YourDomainName.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon
```

or on the ADFS server

```
https://localhost/adfs/ls/IdpInitiatedSignon.aspx
```

If it is not enabled, meaning, the IdP page does not render, etc., then something went wrong with your ADFS install and you need to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm using **Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter** and there is **Bios mode = Legacy**, but my question is, how can I achieve **Enable IdpInitiatedSignon Page** without getting the error on a legacy version of Windows. If I'm getting the error, is there any alternative way to ***Enable IdpInitiatedSignon Page***

Comment: thank you very very very much. It's working fine for me.

Comment: No worries. Remember, if this resolved your use case, please mark this as your accepted answer for the benefit of others, that may have the same concerns.